# What does the usable range depend on in this current sink circuit?

Tags: current, bjt

I'm trying to build a controllable constant current sink circuit. I have found a circuit that I liked and tried a simulation. I wanted to get 0-20mA of current using a 0-2V control signal.

Everything is alright, but if the load resistance gets too high, the current kind of saturates. I couldn't analyze the circuit properly and I can't figure out what is causing this. Could you please give a few opinions?

[image: Circuit Simulation]

Comment: I think you should also add what your specifiations are. No real current source can work on any type of load, there are always ranges.

Answer (score 13):

The limitation is the 28V you are using to supply the current.

If you simplify the load circuit, you'll see what I mean:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNG6Pi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've replaced the transistor with a wire.  When you drive the transistor hard, it acts like a short circuit.

If you calculate the current through just the load and the current detect resistor, then you'll see that you can't get more than 13mA through it.

To get more current through a large value resistor (load,) you'll need a higher voltage power supply. You'd need a supply voltage of at least 40V to get 20mA through your 2k load resistor.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers have told you what is wrong. I'll add some vocabulary so you know what to look for in current sources, or search for when trying to fix it.

Your current source has a **compliance voltage** of about 25 V. That's your power supply, less 2 V for the sensing resistor, less 1 V or so to keep the transistor away from saturation.

That means if you want to drive up to 20 mA output, your load resistance must be less than 25 V / 20 mA = 1250 Ω, to keep the output voltage less than this. Using a larger load will exceed your output compliance voltage.

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source#Background)

Answer (score 4):

You have a voltage of 28 V. The load resistance is 2000\$\Omega\$ and the sense resistance is 100\$\Omega\$, so the maximum current is
$$\frac{28 V}{2000\Omega  + 100\Omega} = 13.333...~ mA$$

So you will never get 20 mA with that voltage and resistance.

You would need to either increase the voltage or lower the resistance.

To find the voltage you would need, take the maximum load resistance, add the sense resistance and multiply by the maximum current you want, then add at least a few volts to account for losses across the transistor.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your Q1 is going into saturation when the load is too high. That simply means that your Q1 Vce has become so small that it behaves pretty much like a resistor. This is because the drop across your load increases as you increase its resistance. It's just ohm's law.

The only thing I can think of right now is that you must increase Vcc.

Comment: Using another transistor won't help.

Comment: @Elec1 you're right, there are small VvE transistors, but in this case it won't help. Will delete that.

Answer (score 0):

To get 20mA to flow through a 2000 ohm resistor requires 40V, and that's not counting the drop across the 100 ohm sense resistor.  Vcc is too low, or use a lower value load resistor